# Python regular expresion how to group last digits and the rest

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get last digits of a text but i need the rest of the group.

I tried using (\d+)?$ expression then replacing the word.

```
import re
text = "kjsdaksjak*?^'{}^^'!11001"
pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+)?$")
match = pattern.search(text)
digit = match.group()
rest = text.replace(digit,"")
```

But is there a better way? Can i group it with regular expressions?
I also tried (.*)(\d+)?$ but it doesn't work.

Comment: So you want to match both the last digits and everything else.

Comment: What should be the result of `kjsdaksjak*?^'{}^^'!11001` ? This will capture what is before the digits in group 1, and optional digits in group 2  `^(.*?)(\d+)?$` see https://regex101.com/r/WsLquX/1

Comment: The fourth bird's answer is what i was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the first part of the string before the digits in group 1, and the optional digits at the right in group 2.

Note that the first quantifier is a `+` to prevent matching an empty string.

```
^(.+?)(\d+)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(.+?)` Capture **group 1**, match as least as possible chars
- `(\d+)?` Optional capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits
- `$` End of string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I8fpzm/1)

If you always want to have group 2 in the code (to not check for the existence of group 2 first), you can also match 0+ digits instead in group 2:

```
^(.+?)(\d*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BRZAjy/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/AuawEV)

Then you should first check if there is a match, as [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) can also return None.

```
import re

text = "kjsdaksjak*?^'{}^^'!11001"
pattern = re.compile(r"^(.+?)(\d*)$")
match = pattern.search(text)

if match:
    print(match.group(1))
    print(match.group(2))
```

Output

```
kjsdaksjak*?^'{}^^'!
11001
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
import re
```

```
r = r'(?=[01]+$)'
s = "kjsdaksjak*?^'{}^^'!11001"
```

```
print(re.split(r, s, 1))
  #=> ["kjsdaksjak*?^'{}^^'!", '11001']
```

[Demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYurSMFWoUhdw9422sAwVltFU52rGCiilJ1VnJKYXZyVmK1lH6deXRsXp65oaGhgYKjExVVQlJlXolGUqldckJMJZOgoFOsoGGpqcv3/DwA)

The last argument of `split` is the maximum number of splits, or one less than the maximum number of strings produced by the split. Without that argument the return value would be

```
["kjsdaksjak*?^'{}^^'!", '1', '1', '0', '0', '1']
```

The regular expression matches the zero-width location preceding the first digit (a `'1'`) that is followed by zero or more digits at the end of the string.

I assume that the digits are to be `0` or `1`. If they can be any digits replace `[01]` with `\d`.